# Why do I get Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError?

Tags: capybara

I tried the following code:

> > page.execute_script " $('#{selector}').trigger('mouseenter').click();"

I can't use use jquery with capybara. (unknown error (**Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError)**)

Can someone suggest to me what I am missing?

I am using capybara (1.1.2), selenium-webdriver(2.29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have double quotation marks in strings unless you escape them. In this scenario though, that can get messy rather quickly. Try this

```
page.execute_script("$('#{selector}').trigger('mouseenter').click();")
```

Comment: I am passing the ID of the web element.

Comment: I understand you're passing in the ID of the element what I meant was what is that id exactly? Are you passing in #foo, or .bar? I ask because this is starting to look like there's a typo in your javascript.